# WCF defining multiple ServiceContracts with different ServiceContract types

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I'm trying to write two completely different types of service contracts, here's one (IService) that should support multiple clients.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallBack), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void GetSquaredAsync();
}

public interface IClientCallBack
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Result(int i);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
class Service : IService
{
 void GetSquaredAsync(double x)
 {
   callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallBack>();
   callback.Result(x * x);
 }
```

And this is another that should only allow for 1 client:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ISuperUser
{
    [OperationContract]
    string WhoIsSpecial(string name);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class SuperUser : ISuperUser
{
    public string WhoIsSpecial(string name)
    {
        return String.Format("{0} is special ^_^", name);
    }
}
```

This is just an example as my actual ServiceContracts with implementations are too big to post here but the idea is the same.  I want one ServiceContract to check on the service with only a few function calls available and a different ServiceContract that uses a Callback and grants access to functions I want only 1 client to have access to at any given time due to synchronization concerns.  Can I make it so that one service host could support both of these ServiceContracts at once?

Comment: Yes you can have two (or more) contracts provided by one service - you just need to write all contracts into config

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm not so sure I understand what you mean.  Could you possibly point me to an appconfig that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I still haven't been able to get around having different ConcurrencyModes for each of my services but I have found that you can combine multiple Service Contracts into one like in this example having

```
class Service : IService, ISuperUser
{
    void GetSquaredAsync(double x)
    {
        callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallBack>();
        callback.Result(x * x);
    }

    public string WhoIsSpecial(string name)
    {
        return String.Format("{0} is special ^_^", name);
    }
}
```

Then I start a servicehost with different endpoints for each interface.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), httpUrl);

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new NetTcpBinding(), IServiceUrl);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISuperUser), new NetTcpBinding(), ISuperUserUrl);

host.Open();
```

Then from the client I can access either of the service contracts independently depending on which one I want to use without exposing the functions of the other.  This also allows me to have one set of functions that use callbacks and another that does not.  Hope this helps someone else.